# Loading MapView before ViewController is loaded

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview

I'm programming an iPhone-app with a `MKMapView` but before the `mapView` is open, you have to click on a button in the `viewController` before.

Is it possible to load the `mapView` before the `viewController` is actually called/the button is tapped so that it doesn't have to load the `mapView`, when the user sees it?

And if there is an opportunity... How does is work?

Thanks! :)

Comment: post the code you have in the button action selector method and also your `viewDidload`

Comment: The button is linked to the VC, which has the MKMapView, through the storyboard! So there is actually no code in the selector method..
The 'viewDidLoad' has just one line of code:
self.mapView.delegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating your `mapView` object in the button action method, move all this `mapView` related code into `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWillAppear`.
It will then load with the view itself and you need not click on any button to show the `mapView`

**EDIT:** (*as per your comments*)
Since you want 2 `viewController`s to be active together, check the following link:
http://www.jacopretorius.net/2013/04/using-multiple-viewcontrollers-on-a-single-screen-in-ios.html

it has to do with using `addChildViewController`

Comment: No!
I meant:
I have 2 VCs, in one is the button in the other one the MapView! And my question is, if there is an opportunity, to load the MapView, while the VC with the button is on screen!

Comment: @MyJBMe : this is on iPad or iPhone?

Comment: @MyJBMe : added a link to the answer that might help